# How to disable default Widget splash effect in Flutter?

Tags: widget, flutter

How can I disable the default splash/ripple/ink effect on a Widget? Sometimes the effect is unwanted, such as in the following TextField case:

[image]

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Per @hunter's suggestion above, I found that by setting both `highlightColor` and `splashColor` in my theme to `Colors.transparent` removed the ripple.

I do hold some concerns that setting `highlightColor` might have some knock-on effects, but I haven't noticed any yet.

**Edit:** While my original answer has loads of up-votes, the more I learn, the more I've realised that it really isn't the right way to do it. As several people have pointed out below, a better solution is to use the `splashFactory`. For example, the code below shows it being set directly via the style, or you can set it in your theme too:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  ),
  child: child,
);
```

Comment: This also removes the ripple effect from widgets such as InkWell and InkResponse

Comment: Setting `highlightColor` to transparent makes using `Theme.of(context).highlightColor` pointless

Comment: Doesn't work for TextButton. `TextButton.styleFrom(splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory);` I can't see why.

Answer (score 77):

You can wrap the component into `Theme` and set the properties `splashColor` and `highlightColor` to transparent on `ThemeData`

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: YourWidget(),
);
```

Comment: Best answer here, not changing whole-app theme! You can even use `Theme.of(context).copyWith` instead of `ThemeData` as it will keep already defined theme data instead of having flutter's default ones :)

Answer (score 32):

#### Use [NoSplash.splashFactory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/splashFactory.html)

**Set to a theme**

```dart
final yourTheme = ThemeData.light();
...
Theme(
  data: yourTheme.copyWith(
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  ),
  ...
)
```

**Set to a material widget**

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  ),
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('No Splash'),
)
```

Answer (score 22):

You can replace the Theme's `splashFactory` with one that doesn't paint anything:

```
class NoSplashFactory extends InteractiveInkFeatureFactory {
  const NoSplashFactory();

  @override
  InteractiveInkFeature create({
    MaterialInkController controller,
    RenderBox referenceBox,
    Offset position,
    Color color,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    bool containedInkWell = false,
    Rect Function() rectCallback,
    BorderRadius borderRadius,
    ShapeBorder customBorder,
    double radius,
    VoidCallback onRemoved,
  }) {
    return NoSplash(
      controller: controller,
      referenceBox: referenceBox,
    );
  }
}

class NoSplash extends InteractiveInkFeature {
  NoSplash({
    @required MaterialInkController controller,
    @required RenderBox referenceBox,
  })  : assert(controller != null),
        assert(referenceBox != null),
        super(
          controller: controller,
          referenceBox: referenceBox,
        );

  @override
  void paintFeature(Canvas canvas, Matrix4 transform) {}
}
```

And wrap your widget with it:

```
child: new Theme(
  data: new ThemeData(splashFactory: const NoSplashFactory()),
  child: new TextField(...),
),
```

*Originally answered by HansMuller on a [GitHub PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/16336#issuecomment-380915096).*

Comment: you could also just define a transparent splashColor; ie: `ThemeData(splashColor: Colors.transparent)`

Comment: The `@override` annotation should be removed as `InteractiveInkFeatureFactory` is an abstract class in latest version of flutter.

Comment: Now it's merged in flutter! Use `splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory`

Answer (score 15):

I'll modify Camilo's approach just to be sure we don't override other properties of the parent theme.

```dart
var color = Colors.transparent;
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    highlightColor: color,
    splashColor: color,
    hoverColor: color,
  ),
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the above answer without success(`splashColor: Colors.transparent, highlightColor: Colors.transparent,`).

My solution was to only set `hoverColor:Colors.transparent`

Comment: actually in order to remove every highlight, hover, splashing effect on an InkWell, I had to set both splashColor, highlightColor and hoverColor as well, but it worked by setting on the inkwell itself, I did not need to use the Theme wrapper

Answer (score 6):

Set `highlightColor`,`splashColor` to **transparent** and `splashFactory` to **NoSplash**  as shown below in your material apptheme.

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: ThemeData(
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,,
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

As I was looking for a way to remove the slash from list overscroll, none of the ThemeData related solutions worked for me. I thought that this question was the same as the one I had, so for any users facing the same misunderstanding, the following solution proved to work, and is pretty neat when put into a stateless widget as you can see below:

```
class NoSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  NoSplash({this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
        onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
          overscroll.disallowGlow();
          return true;
        },
        child: child);
  }
}
```

The way to use this is to simply wrap your widget with NoSplash(child: )

Hope someone finds this useful!

Comment: That looks neat. This question is generally about tap effects though, so I feel like it might be a good idea if you ask a new question like "How to disable scroll glow effect in Flutter"  and answer it yourself. Will likely make it easier to find for people searching for that.

Comment: Yes it took me some time to realize, and then I found part of this elsewhere on SO, so this is why I'm posting it here. In case someone has misunderstood their own needs like me I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while looking for a solution to disable splash on `ElevatedButton`. all solutions presented here did not work for my problem, even though `Theme(data: ThemeData(... NoSplash..))` was working but for some reason did not work. I set `overlayColor:..` in `ButtonStyle()` to transparent like this: `overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),` and worked. hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

for ElevatedButton. (Flutter 2.20+)

```
class NoSplashState extends MaterialStatesController{
  @override
  void update(MaterialState state, bool add) {
  }
}


ElevatedButton(
   statesController: NoSplashState(),
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  // You can use your custom theme like AppTheme.of(context).materialThemeData
  final yourTheme = Theme.of(context) ;
  
  return Theme(
    data: yourTheme.copyWith(
      // removes splash effect
      splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
      // removes color when holding the button
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    child: yourChild
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a widget has `splashColor` and `highColor` like IconButton
set it to transparant.

```
IconButton(
splashColor: Colors.transparent,
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
color: HexColor.fromHex(AppColors.navigationIconColor),
icon: SvgPicture.asset(
  Platform.isAndroid
      ? "assets/back_button_android.svg"
      : "assets/back_button.svg",
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
onPressed: onPress,
```

);