# How to remove splash in a material PageView component?

Tags: flutter

How does one remove the splash in a [material PageView component](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)?
I have tried to set the ThemeData's `accentColor` and `splashColor` to `Colors.transparent`, but this results in a transparent black splash for the entire app.

I have tried to create a `NoSplashContainer` much like from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50020524/9302674) and but the splash remains inside the children.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoSplashContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  NoSplashContainer(this.child) : assert(child != null);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (new Container(
        child: new Theme(
            data: Theme
                .of(context)
                .copyWith(splashFactory: const NoSplashFactory()),
            child: child)));
  }
}

class NoSplashFactory extends InteractiveInkFeatureFactory {
  const NoSplashFactory();

  @override
  InteractiveInkFeature create({
    @required MaterialInkController controller,
    @required RenderBox referenceBox,
    @required Offset position,
    @required Color color,
    bool containedInkWell: false,
    RectCallback rectCallback,
    BorderRadius borderRadius,
    double radius,
    VoidCallback onRemoved,
  }) {
    return new NoSplash(
      controller: controller,
      referenceBox: referenceBox,
    );
  }
}

class NoSplash extends InteractiveInkFeature {
  NoSplash({
    @required MaterialInkController controller,
    @required RenderBox referenceBox,
  })  : assert(controller != null),
        assert(referenceBox != null),
        super(
          controller: controller,
          referenceBox: referenceBox,
        );

  @override
  void paintFeature(Canvas canvas, Matrix4 transform) {}
}
```

I use `NoSplashContainer` like so..

```
new NoSplashContainer(new PageView(
   children: ...,
)));
```

but the splash is still present in the `PageView`.

Comment: can you post some code, what kind of splash?

Comment: @Tree I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `Widget` called [`Theme`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) that will apply a theme to descendant widgets. So, you can use `Theme` to customize any part of your app without modifying theme of the whole app. Something like this:

```
new Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent
      ), 
      child:....
    );
```