# Remove highlight when Flutter's TabBar is tapped

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement my own TabBar design in flutter. I was able to get a pretty good result. However, when I tap another tab to change the tab, there is a highlight create by default as shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBwMg.png). I'm wondering if there is any way I can get rid of the square highlight on tapped. I've been looking around for like almost a day not and did not find any solution.

If anyone have any solution please let me know. Thanks.

Edited: as CopsOnRoad suggestion I wrapped the TabBar in the Container and set the color to `Colors.transparent`, but it does not really disappear so I tried to set the color to `Theme.of(context).canvasColor` for now.

```
    Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        indicator: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFE6E6E6),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(99.0)
          )
        ),
        tabs: List<Widget>.generate(
          categories.length,
          (index) => Tab(
            child: Text(
              categories[index],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Hiragino Sans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Color(0xFF4D4D4D),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ),
      )
    )
```

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the ripple effect. You can remove it by wrapping it in a `Container` and giving transparent color to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay, I tried wrapping both the `TabBar` and `Tab` in the `Container` and set the `color: Colors.transparent` like you recommended. However, it does not disappear. But when I try to wrap the `TabBar` in `Container` and set the `color: ` to anything then it disappear so I'm currently setting it to `color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor`. I'm not sure if I'm missing something but I will update the question.

Answer (score 10):

I had the similar issue. I tried to read the documentation and found it.

```
  ///
  /// If non-null, it is resolved against one of [MaterialState.focused],
  /// [MaterialState.hovered], and [MaterialState.pressed].
  ///
  /// [MaterialState.pressed] triggers a ripple (an ink splash), per
  /// the current Material Design spec.
  ///
  /// If the overlay color is null or resolves to null, then the default values
  /// for [InkResponse.focusColor], [InkResponse.hoverColor], [InkResponse.splashColor],
  /// and [InkResponse.highlightColor] will be used instead.
  final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? overlayColor;
```

Finally just added `overlayColor` to transparent. It solved my issue.

```
overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: nice working for me

Comment: Works awesome thank you so much! This works with Material 3

Answer (score 9):

you should set tabbar `splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory` as this post mentioned.

```
TabBar(splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,)
```

[How to disable default Widget splash effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020523/how-to-disable-default-widget-splash-effect-in-flutter)

Answer (score 4):

You can also disable the ripple/highlight/splash effect with the code below. Add the Theme with the data of ThemeData where the hightlight and splash color is both transparent.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: AppBar( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my custom solution from @Tempelriter

```
     Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.gray,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.red
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'comingSoon'),
              Tab(text: 'selling'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```