# How to disable highlight and splash behavior of TabBar item in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want disable or change `highlightColor` and `splashColor` behavior when tapping on tab item?

My code segment,

```
SliverAppBar(
    backgroundColor: MyColors.darkGreen,
    elevation: 0.0,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    bottom: TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
      labelColor: Colors.white,
      onTap: (int itemIndex) {},
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      indicator: BubbleTabIndicator(
        indicatorHeight: 25.0,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white38,
        tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      ),
      tabs: tabs,
      controller: _tabController,
    ),
    pinned: true,
    floating: false,
    title: _titleWidget,
),
```

Guide me how to make it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

just put your `AppBar` inside Theme with transparent `highlightColor` and `splashColor`.
eg.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: AppBar( ... )
```

Comment: This might help someone https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250502/10599979

Answer (score 16):

For anyone looking for a solution to this, the Flutter team merged in a PR to do just that. Here is how you do it:

```
TabBar(
  splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      // Use the default focused overlay color
      return states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ? null : Colors.transparent;
    }
  ),
  ...
)
```

Here is a link to the PR: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/96252

Comment: This is the best answer since it uses the inbuilt property instead of wrapping with another widget.

Answer (score 10):

Add this in your ThemeData inside MaterialApp.

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: _routes,
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
```

If you only want to disable the splashColor / highlightColor on that specific TabBar, you can wrap your widget in a `Theme` widget. That will override the global ThemeData

Answer (score 6):

follow the process

inside MaterialApp follow this

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
);
```

and inside TabBar follow this property

```
TabBar(
 overlayColor:MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),
 // above property will remove splash color or it will provider whatever color you want
 tabs:<Widget>[
   Tab(),
 ],
),
```

hope this will help you!!
thank you.

Comment: I didn't wrap in MaterialApp.  just added    overlayColor:MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),

and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can only wrap the TabBar inside Theme() and set the splashColor

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData().copyWith(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: TabBar(
    ...)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `splashFactory` for `TabBar`:

```
TabBar(
   splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory ,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add de following code:

`TabBar( overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => Colors.transparent), )`