remove ripple splash effect on tabbing tabbar flutter
I try Remove ripple effect on tab bar when tab or click on TabBar
this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914982/remove-highlight-when-flutters-tabbar-is-tapped#:~:text=That's%20the%20ripple%20effect.,giving%20transparent%20color%20to%20it.
remove background for normal status but still show effect when click or tap on tab bar
i also try this answers :
How to disable default Widget splash effect in Flutter?
but that answers i think only work on buttons or another widgets ... not working on TabBar
here is my code and as you see i try all ways but still show tab effect when click :
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
    MaterialApp(
  title: "App",
  home: Sample(),
    ),
);


class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackOverState createState() => _StackOverState();
}

class _StackOverState extends State<Sample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  final yourTheme = ThemeData.light();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(
          'Tab bar',
        ),
      ),
      body:
          Theme(
            data: yourTheme.copyWith(
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,

            ),
              child:  Column(
                children: [
                  // give the tab bar a height [can change hheight to preferred height]
                  Container(

                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                      height: 45,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child:

                      Container(
                       color:Colors.transparent,
                        child:
                        TabBar(
                          splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
                          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          controller: _tabController,
                          // give the indicator a decoration (color and border radius)
                          indicator:
                          BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              25.0,
                            ),
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                          labelColor: Colors.white,
                          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                          tabs: [
                            // first tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                            Tab(
                              child:
                              Container(
                                //   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child:
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child:Text("Place Bid"),
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                            // second tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                            Tab(
                              child:
                              Container(
                                //    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child:
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text("buy now"),
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )



                  ),
                  // tab bar view here
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: [
                        // first tab bar view widget
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Place Bid',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        // second tab bar view widget
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Buy Now',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],),)

      );

  }
}



To achieve a transparent ripple effect in a TabBar, you need to override the tabBarTheme in your app's ThemeData. Specifically:
Set the splashFactory:
Use InkRipple.splashFactory or any other desired splash factory to define the ripple behavior.
Provide an overlayColor:
The overlayColor property determines the ripple and hover effects.
Returning null for all states effectively disables the color overlay while keeping the splash animation intact.
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        title: "App",
        home: Sample(),
      ),
    );

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({super.key});

  @override
  _StackOverState createState() => _StackOverState();
}

class _StackOverState extends State<Sample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  final yourTheme = ThemeData.light();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Tab bar',
        ),
      ),
      body: Theme(
        data: yourTheme.copyWith(
          tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
            overlayColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
              (states) {
                 return Colors.transparent; // Default
              },
            ),
            splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory, // Ripple effect for TabBar
          ),
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              height: 45,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  25.0,
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) {
                    _tabController.animateTo(
                      index,
                      duration: Duration.zero, // Disables animation
                      curve: Curves.linear,
                    );
                  },
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  controller: _tabController,
                  // give the indicator a decoration (color and border radius)
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                      25.0,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: [
                    // first tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                    Tab(
                      child: Container(
                        //   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text("Place Bid"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // second tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                    Tab(
                      child: Container(
                        //    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text("buy now"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // tab bar view here
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  // first tab bar view widget
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Place Bid',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // second tab bar view widget
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Buy Now',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


thank you for answer , but still the same problem ... test your code and you will see gray background in corner when u click on tab

i also add image out put , see

dear the above answer before update it , was working on mobile I tested it and was working fine , I update the code now its working also on both web and mobile hope it works with you , @Erfan

i think this is the most complete answer about this issue , i give +vote and accept as answer , thank you

no worries dear anytime @Erfan
