# How to make BottomNavigationBarItem not clickable and disable tap splash effect?

Tags: flutter

I have BottomNavigationBar with 5 items and also FloatingActionButton that should change 3rd item 'Photo'.

So I need if user press on central BottomNavigationBarItem 'Photo' it didn't affect switching to this tab.

How can I disable clicking on specific BottomNavigationBarItem?

[image: BottomNavigationBar with FloatingActionButton]

And here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => new _MainPageState();
}

class PageInfoData {
  final String title;
  final IconData iconData;

  const PageInfoData(this.title, this.iconData);
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const List<PageInfoData> pageInfo = [
    PageInfoData('History', Icons.swap_horiz),
    PageInfoData('Download', Icons.file_download),
    PageInfoData('Photo ', null),
    PageInfoData('Upload', Icons.file_upload),
    PageInfoData('Settings', Icons.settings)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text("Menu"),
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,),)],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('Index$_selectedIndex: ${pageInfo[_selectedIndex].title}')),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: new List<BottomNavigationBarItem>.generate(pageInfo.length, (int index) {
          PageInfoData curPageInfo = pageInfo[index];
          return BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(curPageInfo.iconData, size: 30.0), title: Text(curPageInfo.title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0),));
        }),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xff797979),
        fixedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffe2e2e2),
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffa2a5a4),
        child: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, size: 40.0,),
          onPressed: null),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Problem almost solved (thank you @ibhavikmakwana) by changing `_onItemTapped` function

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (index != 2) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }
```

But it solved not completely.
When I tap photo label it still show me a tap splash effect.
**Can I disable a tap splash effect?**

[image]

Comment: Can you show some you code, what you have tried?

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana I updated post with some code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like below:

Your `bottomNavigationBar`

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      ...
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      ...
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      ...
    ),
  ],
  onTap: navigationTapped,
  currentIndex: _page,
),
```

You can add the conditional check whether the page index match with the current index than don't do anything and return from that point.

Like `page == index`

Where, `index` is position of the `BottomNavigationBarItem`

```
void navigationTapped(int page) {
  if (page == 1) {
    return;
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = page;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to solve my problem. But another problem, that splash affect still shown. Can I disable this affect when I tap?

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue as yours. In my case, I just only want to apply it on bottomNavigationBar, because I have splash effect on another widget.

I fixed it using this code below:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(),
),
```

Answer (score 14):

To extend the correct answers given here, the right way to disable the splash effect, is to copy the existing app ThemeData and override **only** the splashColor and highlighColor properties (Otherwise the other app ThemeData properties will be lost).

Wrap your widget with Theme and use the **copyWith** method as follows:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: YourWidget(),
);
```

Comment: This is the right answer for color and removing splash, copyWith...

Comment: Thanks for the insight and proper way to do this. Appreciated for the best practice!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try this to disable splash effect:

Change the `splashColor` or `splashFactory` in `ThemeData` to `Colors.transparent`.

Reference:
[How to disable default Widget splash effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020523/how-to-disable-default-widget-splash-effect-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3):

To disable the splash effect in BottomNavigationBar, wrap it in a Theme widget, and override the values of splashColor and highlightColor with Colors.transparent.