# How to make _card open a new route/page when I tap it, in this particular case?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to make _card open a new route/page when I tap it, in this particular case?

```
Widget _Row() {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                _card(
                    primary: LightColor.purple,
                    backWidget:
                        _decorationContainerA(LightColor.lightOrange),
                    chipColor: LightColor.purple,
                    chipText1: "General info here",
                    chipText2: "TAP TO OPEN",
                    isPrimaryCard: true,
                    imgPath: ""),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your _card with `GestureDetector` or `InkWell`

```
      GestureDetector(
                 _card(
                    primary: LightColor.purple,
                    backWidget:
                        _decorationContainerA(LightColor.lightOrange),
                    chipColor: LightColor.purple,
                    chipText1: "General info here",
                    chipText2: "TAP TO OPEN",
                    isPrimaryCard: true,
                    imgPath: ""
                 ),
             onTap: () {}
             )
```

```
 InkWell(
        onTap: () {}
          _card(
                    primary: LightColor.purple,
                    backWidget:
                        _decorationContainerA(LightColor.lightOrange),
                    chipColor: LightColor.purple,
                    chipText1: "General info here",
                    chipText2: "TAP TO OPEN",
                    isPrimaryCard: true,
                    imgPath: ""
                 ),
              ),
```

Comment: It worked with InkWell but it has the splash/ripple effect. Is there any way to disable it or make it transparent? I tried to wrap it in Ink widget but does not work. Thank you again!

Comment: I m glad it helped. Please accept my answer by tick the answer. and this how-to disables the ripple effect from a widget. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020523/how-to-disable-default-widget-splash-effect-in-flutter.