# Is there a way to remove the splash from my list tile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following list tile

```
  Container buildContactTile(BuildContext context, Color backgroundColor, Color foregroundColor, UserModel contact,
      ContactListController controller) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: backgroundColor, borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: ProfileAvatar(
          backgroundColor: foregroundColor,
          photoURL: contact.photoURL,
          radius: 15.0,
          fallback: ProfileAvatar.nameAvatar(displayName: contact.displayName),
        ),
        title: Text(contact.displayName, style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1.apply(color: foregroundColor)),
        trailing: _interactive ? Icon(Icons.add, color: foregroundColor) : null,
        onTap: () => _interactive ? controller.updateSelectedContacts(contact) : null,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And I wrap it with a container to give it a different background color depending on the state of the widget. But what happens is that my splash does not account for the circular border radius so the splash color ends up appearing in the corners of the list tile. How can I make the splash color transparant, or make it account for the rounded corners?

When you press on the ListTile and hold you see the following in the corners

[image]

Comment: can you add images of how the screen looks?

Comment: Added a picture what it looks like when you press the list tile

Comment: I am reading through [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) docs, i think by wrapping `ListTile` in `InkWell` we might be able to configure the touch ripple to account for the rounded corners by setting `containedInkWell:true` in `InkWell`

Comment: Just tried it but it does not work

Comment: Found a workaround, have tried in dartpad but not sure if it will work as you want. Try and tell.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry my laptop crashed I hope to test it tommorow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the entire `Container` in `Theme` and set `ThemeData`'s `splashColor` and `highlightColor` to `Colors.transparent`.

Reference [How to disable default Widget splash effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58673392/13625305)

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
          title: const Text("Trix's airplane"),
          subtitle: const Text('The airplane is only in Act II.'),
          enabled: true,
          onTap: () {
            print('Something');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Only just had time to test it, but it did not resolve the problem sadly.

Comment: If you tap quickly it looks like it is fixed. But when you hold you finger on the tile for a longer time youll see the corners becoming black.

Comment: Updated, found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020523/how-to-disable-default-widget-splash-effect-in-flutter)