# How to disable a ripple effect in Inkwell widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying to implement inkwell widget,but after tapping on the widget it shows the ripple effect.How can I disable the ripple effect?

I tired to change the ripple effect color to Tranperent but it doesn't goes well is there any solution or should i go with GestureDetector Widget.

Comment: It is better if you can add some code along with current result as you mentioned that transparent color solution not working good for you

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58673392/4615232 or others in that topic.